# How Can I move Type to Search Text Down?

Tags: html

I was coding my website when I realized that my Type to search button is quite high on the Website. Is there a way that I can get that to come down a bit? Here is my code For this project. Also if you see anyway that I can improve this website please tell me, also could you please help give me some tips on how I can make my code neater and more readable. Over all the type to search is the biggest problem to fix but if you see some others please let me know. Thank you!

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Webpage</title>
        <link href="context/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="Webfonts/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul class="navbarlist">

                <li class="navbarimg"><img class="navbarlogo" src="img/LOGO.png"></li>
                <li class="navbarelementL">Browse</li>
                <li class="navbarelementL">Today's Deals</li>
                <li class="navbarelementR">Shopping Cart</li>

            </ul>
            <div class="searchbox">
                <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type to Search">
                <a class="search-btn" href="#"></a>
                <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="banner">
            <img class="titleimg" src="img/TITLE.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
              <img src="img/Grid Panel 1.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <img src="img/Grid Panel 1.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <img src="img/Grid Panel 1.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="bottomnav">
          <div class="bottomlogo">
            <img class="navbarlogo2" src="img/LOGO.png">
          </div>

          <div class='nav'>
            <div class='left'>
              <ul>
                <li class="bottomelement">About Us</li>
                <li class="bottomelement">Affiliates</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class='right'>
              <ul>
                <li class="bottomelement">TOS</li>
                <li class="bottomelement">Fourth </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

## CSS

```
/*General*/
h2{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
}
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
/*Navbar*/
.navbar{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(248, 138, 180);
}
.navbarlogo{
    width: 60px;
    height: auto;
}
.navbarlist{
    list-style-type:none;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

.navbarelementL{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    float: left;
}

.navbarelementL:hover{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.navbarelementR{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    float:right;
}

.navbarelementR:hover{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

 /*end*/
.navbarimg{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
    float:left;
}
.popupnavimg{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
    float:left;
}
.popupimg{
    width: 40px;
    height:auto;
}
.searchbox{
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.searchbox:hover > .search-txt{
    width: 240px;
    padding: 0 6px;
}
.searchbox:hover > .search-btn{
    background: white;
}
.search-btn{
    color: black;
    float: right;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: skyblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.7s;

}
.search-txt{
    border:none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 0.7s;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 0;
}
.fas{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 18.0px;
    margin-top: 18.5px;
    size: 40px;;
}

.titleimg{
    width:100%;
}

/*grid1*/

/* Three image containers (use 25% for four, and 50% for two, etc) */
.row {
    display: flex;
  }

  .column {
    flex: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  body {
    margin:0
  }

  body {
    margin:0
  }

  .bottomnav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(248, 138, 180);
    position: relative;
  }

  .navbarlogo2 {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 120px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    filter: brightness(10);
    top: 15px;
    left: calc(50% - 60px) /*center top left corner then remove half logo width (120px)*/
  }

  /*bottombar*/
  .nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 120px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .nav ul {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  .left,
  .right {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .bottomelement{
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .bottomelement:hover{
    font-size: 25px;
    transition-duration: 1s;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `margin-top` to

```
.search-txt {
    //...
    margin-top: 7px;
}
```

Check the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ca6prsjv/)

To answer your other questions, normally IDE's has formatting options included. Else you can use online sites like [cleancss.com](https://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/) for CSS or [htmlformatter.com](https://htmlformatter.com/) for HTML or [beautifier.io](https://beautifier.io/) for JavaScript.